# Software to convert source code to pdf in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, pdf

Is there any choice for converting source code to pdf for reading?

I'm using Linux Mint and I'm looking for some command line solutions.

Comment: Have you already seen these questions? On [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129029/a-light-solution-to-convert-text-to-pdf-in-linux), on [Unix & Linux.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-convert-txt-to-pdf) and on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27097/how-to-print-a-regular-file-to-pdf-from-command-line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a virtual printer like `cups-pdf` and print the code:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

If this is the only or the default printer in your system, then [printing](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html) is as easy as:

```
lpr <file_with_code>
```

If you're looking for nice formatted code here are the options:

```
sudo apt-get install code2html
```

Use this to [convert](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/code2html/) source code file to html file which you can then print using the above command.

If you want a GUI solution, you can use [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) editor, which can either print directly, convert to `rtf` and `html` which then can be printed/converted to `pdf`.

Comment: I've tried **code2html**, it worked perfect. And for converting to PDF I've used LibreOffice feature export to PDF, because I don't know where **cups-pdf** put PDF files.

Comment: @MilosDolobac look in the `~/PDF` folder.

Answer (score 3):

[Enscript](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/enscript) is a general command that pretty-prints ASCII text.  It can even do [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649452/1157100) for most common languages with the `-E` option.

Example usage, to typeset a file with 2-up layout and a fancy header in landscape mode, with C++ syntax highlighting:

```
enscript -2Gr -Ecpp -o output_file.pdf input_file.cpp
```